# Devise authentication as API only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, angularjs, http-post, http-get

I'm trying to use Devise authentication with Angular.js. Everything is already working except I want to hide the server-side login form, i.e. the result of `/users/sign_in` `GET` request leaving only the possibility of `/users/sign_in` `POST` request. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to skip sessions in your devise_for call in routes.rb (or not even call it) and just stick to devise_scope for setting up your sign_in path.  So, your routes.rb would look like this:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => :sessions

devise_scope do
  post "/users/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#create"
  delete "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
```

Comment: Does this mean that my custom SessionsController (the overridden "create" method) won't function?

Comment: No, the post to create should still function. It's limiting the scope of the included SessionsController so that rails won't recognize a request for get /users/sign_in as a valid route.