# Ruby on Rails will not register active_admin upon server startup (http://localhost:3001/admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I am currently creating my first React-on-Rails project. I have an issue with loading the server when trying to run the RoR api.

Application.rb

```
    require_relative 'boot'

    require "rails"
    # Pick the frameworks you want:
    require "active_model/railtie"
    require "active_job/railtie"
    require "active_record/railtie"
    require "active_storage/engine"
    require "action_controller/railtie"
    require "action_mailer/railtie"
    require "action_view/railtie"
    require "action_cable/engine"
    require "sprockets/railtie"
    require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

    # Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
    # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
    Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

    module ListOfIngredients
    class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated 
    Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those 
    specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in 
    config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded 
    after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only 
    apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back 
    manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.
    config.api_only = true

    # Middleware for ActiveAdmin
    config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
    end
    end
```

Gemfile.

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

   ruby '2.5.1'

   # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
   gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
   # Use Puma as the app server
   gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
   # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
   https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
   # gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
   # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
   # gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
   # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
   # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

   # Use ActiveStorage variant
   # gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

   # Use Capistrano for deployment
   # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

   # Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
   gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

   # Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing 
   (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
   # gem 'rack-cors'

   group :development, :test do
   # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
   gem 'sqlite3'
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a 
   debugger console
   gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
   end

   group :development do
   gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application 
   running in the background. Read more: 
   https://github.com/rails/spring
   gem 'spring'
   gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
   end

   group :production do
   # Use postgres as the database for production
   gem 'pg'
   end

   # ActiveAdmin
   gem 'devise'
   gem 'activeadmin'

   # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo- 
   data gem
   gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, 
   :jruby]
```

I have also set up two controllers as follows.

api_controller.rb

```
   class ApiController < ActionController::API
   end
```

application_controller.rb

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    end
```

When I am running rails on localhost 3001, I somehow still end up with the error message.

Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

where are active admins assets supposed to go when rails 5 api doesn't contain an assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure ActiveAdmin requires sprockets.  Did you run?

```
rails generate devise:install
```

You might also need to run

```
rails generate devise:views
```

For more info on vies see the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)

And perhaps a [look at this answer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728211/devise-authentication-as-api-only)  and [this one too](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#rails-api-mode)

UPDATE:

If you are following instructions at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/superhighfives/a-top-shelf-web-stack-rails-5-api-activeadmin-create-react-app-de5481b7ec0b) you might wanna try to comment out this line in application.rb

```
# require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestions. However, I end up with the same result, after installing the devise, as well as the views.

Comment: I have solved it now by manually adding the active_admin assets. Not sure if it's good to consistently stop the spring but for now, I have the API running. Thanks for your help!